# Why must I restart my server after a db:reset in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Whenever I run `rake db:reset` to clear my sqlite database in my rails develop environment, it seems I have to kill my server and restart it otherwise my app will act as if there are AR objects in the db. I'm a ruby noobie fyi. Is it due to AR caching the objects in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Could be somewhat related to Rails AR or schema caching. If restarting the server works for you, then I am assuming it clears the schema cache